Problem with lua's load function
I use the load function to create a lua function using a mathematical expression. The purpose is to draw the curve corresponding to this expression.
I have two codes to get what I want, but I'm having trouble with one of them (the second one).
The first is this:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  
\makeatletter\let\percentchar\@percentchar\makeatother

\def\calcval#1#2#3#4{%
 \directlua{
local min = #2
local max = #3
local nb = #4
local f
local tbl = {}
    
  f = load (([[
        return function (x)
            return (\percentchar s)
        end
    ]]):format ([[#1]]), nil, 't', math) ()

    for t = min,max,(max-min)/nb  do
        x = t
        y = f(t)
        table.insert (tbl, "("..x..","..y..")")
     end
     tex.print(table.concat (tbl))
 }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[smooth] plot coordinates {\calcval{sin(x)+x}{-2}{5}{16}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

From the manual: load (chunk [, chunkname [, mode [, env]]]).
This allows you to use the math module, and uses fairly simple syntax.
Arguments are transferred using the \calcval macro.
The second code that gives me problems is :
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  
\makeatletter\let\percentchar\@percentchar\makeatother

\directlua{
function calcval (expr,min,max,nb)
    local myfunc = load("return "..expr)
    local tbl = {}
  % f = load (([[
  %       return function (t)
  %           return (\percentchar s)
  %       end
  %   ]]):format ([[expr]]), nil, 't', math) ()

    for t = min,max,(max-min)/nb  do
        x = t
        y = myfunc ()
        table.insert (tbl, "("..x..","..y..")")
     end
  return table.concat (tbl)
end
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw plot[smooth] coordinates {\directlua{tex.print(calcval("math.sin(x)+x",-2,5,16))}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

The fundamental change is that this time I'm using a lua function calcval.
This imposes constraints because I have to transfer the expression as a string, but I also have to use the lua syntax: math.sin.
What I can't get is a myfunc function with a parameter.
What I'd like to know is whether it's possible to use load as in the first code and whether it's possible to have a function with one argument and avoid the lua syntax (sin and not math.sin).

so you ideally want to type e.g. \directlua{tex.print(calcval(sin(x)+x,-2,5,16))}?

@cfr Yes but I think it's difficult in this case to avoid to use a string : "sin(x)+x". I'd especially like to be able to have a function with an argument, as in the first code : myfunc(2) instead of x=2 myfunc()

I think if calling from Lua it's more natural to pass in a function rather than a string that you need to evaluate.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  
\makeatletter\let\percentchar\@percentchar\makeatother

\directlua{
function calcval (myfunc,min,max,nb)
    local tbl = {}
    for x = min,max,(max-min)/nb  do
        y = myfunc (x)
        table.insert (tbl, "("..x..","..y..")")
     end
  return table.concat (tbl)
end
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw plot[smooth] coordinates {\directlua{
           tex.print(calcval(function (x) return math.sin(x)+x end,-2,5,16))}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


In comments you indicated that you were not keen on the Lua anonymous function syntax, so I add another version showing how use of a standard Lua function allows any other standard Lua function, so the same output here just passing a user defined function f in to your plot function.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  
\makeatletter\let\percentchar\@percentchar\makeatother

\directlua{
function calcval (myfunc,min,max,nb)
    local tbl = {}
    for x = min,max,(max-min)/nb  do
        y = myfunc (x)
        table.insert (tbl, "("..x..","..y..")")
     end
  return table.concat (tbl)
end
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \directlua{
    function f (x)
      return math.sin(x)+x
    end
    }
  \draw plot[smooth] coordinates {\directlua{tex.print(calcval(f,-2,5,16))}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


and measles is more natural than MMR vaccine.

Compared to the first code, I still have the same disadvantages: I still have to use lua's syntax and if I want to calculate and use the function punctually, I have to rewrite everything.

@AlainMatthes maybe I didn't understand the question. I thought using Lua's syntax in Lua was a feature not a problem (compared to using a string). I don't understand your second comment about rewriting. (I suspect "punctually" didn't translate well) but perhaps cfr understood your question better and her answer is more what you want, which is OK the site allows you to choose:-)

From a user's point of view, it's not very cool to write function (x) return math.sin(x)+x end

@AlainMatthes that is the lua syntax for an inline function, some languages have a shorthand syntax like x => x+2 but Lua just doesn't. I see luatex as enabling use of Lua in tex, not to change Lua syntax.  If you don't like the Lua anonymous function syntax you could use a named function and use an argument foo that just passes in the function that you have defined elsewhere. eg plot sin function just needs calcval(math.sin,-2,5,16))}}

I prefer the syntax to be that of Tikz in the tikzpicture environment. For the function, I'd like to have the same possibilities as in my first code (the one with the calcval macro) to use the math module and obtain a function f such that f(x) = sin(x)+x. So for t=3 y = myfunc(t) whereas in my code you need x=t then y =myfunc ()

@AlainMatthes if you have defined such a function f then all you need to do is pass in the single character f

But the point of this answer is to show (what I see as) the benefits of using Lua syntax here, so I can't really address your concerns with small edits: they woruld need a different answer, which is fine, I can not win them all:-)

@AlainMatthes in comments on another answer you commented you wanted to re-use a function f, I'm not sure if it is what you mean but I added a second example that used a defined function f rather than the inline function syntax.

@DavidCarlisle yes I had just come to this conclusion and solution!

@AlainMatthes sorry I should have made that clearer in the original post, my original point was that by allowing a Lua function you had available all Lua syntax and so didn't have to implement and document a custom syntax.

I want a better crystal ball :-). or maybe just a better brain.

I realised what most puzzles me about this: how is f standard pgf/tikz syntax? math.sin(x) + x seems much more intuitive than f. I'm obviously missing something, but I just don't get the idea at all.

@cfr it's not a pgf function it's a lua one. The point is that if you define calcval to take a string argument to denote the function then you need to specify the syntax, but if calcval takes a function any lya function is allowed

@DavidCarlisle that's not what puzzles me. what puzzles me is why asking users to say math.sin is undesirable in a tikz environment, but f is not? aren't both 'lua's syntax'?

Simple things should be solved simply:
\load[tikz]

\def\coord #1#2#3#4{\directlua{
   local nb = (#3-(#2))/#4
   for x = #2,#3,nb  do
      y = #1
      tex.print ("("..x..","..y..")")
   end
}}

\tikzpicture
\draw plot[smooth] coordinates {\coord {math.sin(x)+x} {-2}{5}{16}} ;
\endtikzpicture

\bye

This example is based on OpTeX. If you are using another LuaTeX format, get inspiration from this only.

I like the simplicity of this code, but there are still two obstacles to avoid: the “math.sin” syntax and, above all, the definition of a function f: f(x) = sin(x)+x. I'd like to be able to reuse this function.

@AlainMatthes If you want to use sin instead math.sin, then you ca use OpTeX trick 0143 os simply declare \mathinexpr in OpTeX document.  Ad 2: The macro parameter text can be reused similarly like function. There is no limitation.

@AlainMatthes perhaps I don't understand the question. I understand the point about the math.sin vs sin syntax, but I don't understand how the 'above all' part applies to my answer. apologies to wipet for responding here, but the comment here is for both our answers.
